# iOS push notification and background

Tags: ios, background, push-notification

I have a question about **remote-notification** for background mode. Can my application run `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` when my iphone "background app refresh" is off.

Comment: why I run my app in debug mode and turn off "background app refresh". It still runs this function?

Answer (score 0):

It will call the didReceiveRemoteNotification method. The "*background app refresh*" turn off is stop the background processes of you app. But the "*remote notification*" is handled by the APNS server. That will not stop your push notifications.